# Error in DB SQLite Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a problem coping my DB to my APK...

I found this code, and im using it but that sends me the error:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Archivo no encontrado.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();//FILE DOESNT FOUND
```

This is the code...

```
private void copiarBaseDatos() {
    String ruta = "/data/data/com.example.bbay/databases/";
    String archivo = "DBBay";
    File archivoDB = new File(ruta + archivo);
    if (!archivoDB.exists()) 
    {
        try 
        {
            InputStream IS = getApplicationContext().getAssets().open(archivo);
            OutputStream OS = new FileOutputStream(archivoDB);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length = 0;
            while ((length = IS.read(buffer))>0)
            {
                OS.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
            OS.flush();
            OS.close();
            IS.close();
        } 
        catch(FileNotFoundException e) 
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Archivo no encontrado.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();//FILE DOESNT FOUND
        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error al copiar la Base de Datos.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

any help is wellcome, thanks.

Comment: First of all you hard-coded the path to your app's private data directory. You should not do that and instead take a look at this documentation page: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal  -- The cause for that problem may be that the directory structure `/data/data/com.example.bbay/databases/` does not yet exist. Try creating these directories first with the `mkdirs` method of `File`.

Comment: That solve my problem, than you... I created the folder first with makedir() and it works.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
this.getApplicationContext
```

Comment: Better say also, WHERE he should try it. And what he has to expect. And WHY.